# Models not included in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, model

I am really new to Zend Framework and am using it on regular Apache 2 + PHP server.

I want to use my models which extend Zend_Table_Abstract. I put it in my /application/models directory but these files do not even get included (they have syntax errors but my app works just fine). What are the required actions to get them included? What should be done in Bootstrap and what naming conventions should be followed? I've seen people using just regular names like *Users* or *Articles*.

`/application/models/Languages.php:`

```
<?php
adasdasdadasd
echo 'hi';

class Languages extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name = 'languages';
}
```

`/application/controllers/LanguageController.php`

```
<?php

class LanguagesController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        $languages = new Languages();

        $this->view->languages = $languages->select();
    }
}
```

`/application/Bootstrap.php` (some code is there just because I copied it from some example or answer)

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
    protected function _initAutoload() {
        $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH)
        );

        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace(array('Application_'));

        return $moduleLoader;
    }

    protected function _initResourceAutoloader()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' => 'Application_',
        ));

        return $autoloader;
    }

    protected function _initFrontController()
    {
        $controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

        $controller->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers');

        if ($controller->getParam('bootstrap') === null) {
            $controller->setParam('bootstrap', $this);
        }

        return $controller;
    }

    protected function _initApplication() {
    }

    protected function _initModuleConfig()
    {
    }

    protected function _initLayout(){ 
        return Zend_Layout::startMvc(); 
    }

    protected function _initViewHelpers() {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
        $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
        $view->headTitle('My Application');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/general.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/navigation.css');
    }

    protected function _initNavigation() {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();

        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');

        $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
        $view->navigation($navigation);
    }
}
```

`/application/configs/application.ini`:

```
[production]

; Models
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/"

; Debug output
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

; Bootstrap
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

; Database
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dabase"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

[development : production]

; Debug output
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

; Database
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dabase"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Comment: Show us the way you're instantiating your model object

Comment: Does it matter? It's not even getting included (the file). Will paste some code.

Comment: Yes it may matter. This may be lazy loading issue

Comment: Which lazy loading issue are you referring to @heximal? -.-'

Comment: Did you try $languages = new Default_Model_Languages();

Comment: ZF uses special naming rules for lazy loading. Underlining is used as substitution of slash symbol for populating relative path to apropriate php file

Comment: @heximal Does not even trigger inclusion. It simply says it's not defined.

Comment: Do you declare Languages class as class Default_Model_Languages ?

Comment: I did when tried using it. But I now found out that if I leave namespace as an ampty string (in Bootstrap.php), I can get rid of `Application_` part entirely and it works. It's as simple as `Model_Languages`.

Comment: @Pius Also, change to this $this->view->languages = $languages->fetchAll(); You want the objects, not the select statement, right? You'll not use fetchAll() in your views, I hope :) I recommend you to follow this tutorial instead http://alex-tech-adventures.com/ There's a lot to improve. Good luck.

Comment: @Keyne, thanks. Yes, I wasn't really going to use it later on. It was pretty much for testing purpose only. Thank you for the link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [load other classes with zend autoloader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787405/load-other-classes-with-zend-autoloader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the way you name your models, because Zend autoloader can't simply find the right file idue to way it loads models. So instead of having model like this:

```
class Language extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
....
}
```

you should name it like this:

```
class Application_Model_Language extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
....
}
```

and then instantiate:

```
$languages = new Application_Model_Language();
```

Please note models are mapped differently and your `Application_Model_Language` model class have to be placed in `application/models/Language.php` for this to work.

Comment: It then looks for `Application/Model/Languages.php` to include.

Comment: no, it would look for `application/models/Language.php`. Some components are mapped artificially, and this is the case.

Comment: What I mean is I now get `Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Application/Models/Languages.php' for inclusion` with a couple more very similar warnings.

Comment: Didn't get the part about the "lazy load issue". What this  have with lazy loading? IIRC, this is about namespaces and autoload. You also forgot to post the correct name of the controller. It's wrong on the OP's question.

Comment: @pius: odd. post your application.ini

Comment: comment out `includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/"
` and add `resources.modules[] = ` and let me know

Comment: One more question - is this your first Zend project? If so, where you get your Bootstrap from?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com nothing changed. Did that line have no affect? :| And yes, it is my first Zend project. I built it by using code from a coupe tutorials. Basically 2 or 3 tutorials + something I tried before postng here.

Comment: My BAD. I mistyped your solution. I wrote `new Application_Models_Languages()` instead. Really sorry. Your answer is good :)

Comment: What you call `lazy loader` I call just `autoloader`. Are you sure you know what lazy loading is? http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html